# Condition to check if object's class is a date

Tags: java, jstl, el

I want to check if an object is a class and do some formatting if it is a date. How would I set the `if` condtion?

```
<table align="center" class="data_extract vert_scroll_table" >
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="heading" items="${results.headings}"> 
      <th class="data_extract">${heading}</th>
    </c:forEach>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.data}">
    <tr>
      <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
        <td class="data_extract">
          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
              <c:set var="comma" value="," />
              <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                <c:set var="myVar" value="${cellStatus.first ? '' : myVar} ${elem} ${cellStatus.last ? '' : comma}" /> 
              </c:forEach>
              <span class="mouseover_text" title="${myVar}">${myVar}</span>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
              <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].componentType.class.name eq 'java.sql.Timestamp'}"> 
                  <fmt:formatDate value="${cell}" pattern="${date_pattern}" />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                  ${cell}
                </c:otherwise>
              </c:choose>
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
        </td>
      </c:forEach>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSTL will invoke standard setter getters so you can use getClass() and getName() method

```
<c:if test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].componentType.class.name 
              eq 'java.util.Date' }">
```

Comment: I updated the code.  the results still come back as 2011-04-21 00:00:00.0  which is the else statement if the condition fails

Comment: when i printr out the result.types I get "class java.sql.Timestamp"

Comment: Then just compare to that instead.

Comment: this worked: `<c:when test="${cell.class.name eq 'java.sql.Timestamp' }">`